# Need ubuntu 18.04.4 with 5.3 kernel, not 5.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, linux-kernel

I had an 18.04.4 version of ubuntu that I recently upgraded, and lo and behold the kernel
upgraded to 5.4, which is **not** what I wanted, as I have hardware that doesn't work on 5.4.
I tried re-installing with 18.04.4 from usb, but it once again automatically upgrades me to 5.4

How can I install 18.04.4 without a kernel upgrade ?

Thanks!

Comment: Eh? What hardware doesn't work on 5.4?

Comment: FPGA - no driver support yet

Comment: Well that's odd. It's not like they're in the habit of just removing drivers. And it seems to be present in 5.4. Sounds like something else is going on.

Comment: What particular hardware do you have that isn't working after the upgrade? Have you looked in the logs and examined `dmesg`?

Comment: Trust me, I do not want kernel 5.4

Comment: Maybe, but you'll have to solve the underlying problem eventually. Putting it off just accumulates more technical debt.

Answer (score 0):

Have been successfully using [**Ukuu**](https://teejeetech.in/ukuu/) to install newer kernels on older Ubuntu.

There is a one time low fee, but it is worth it, as the tool is nice and efficient.

You could downgrade to 5.3, but maybe it is better to find an higher version that has what you want.

[image]